# Docx4j repeat Table header every next page

Tags: java, docx4j

I use Docx4j library to create documents based on chosen schema and data. Base function described below.
It seems to work, but if my table take more than one page, I would like header to be repeated. I've tried "repeat the header lines" option in word, but does not seems to work properly.
Probably I should unpack docx and dig in xml file, but what should I look for ?

Thanks in advance

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> fillDocument(@RequestBody String json, @PathVariable Long id) throws Exception {

    DocumentSchemaDTO documentSchema = documentSchemaService.findOne(id).get();

    String xmlStream = documentSchemaService.jsonToXmlClean(json);

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(documentSchema.getFile());
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(inputStream);
    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML);
    Docx4jProperties.setProperty("docx4j.toc.BookmarksIntegrity.remediate", true);

    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, out, Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    byte[] document = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) out).toByteArray();

    GeneratedDocumentDTO generatedDocument = new GeneratedDocumentDTO();
    generatedDocument.setFile(document);
    generatedDocument.setName("Dokument: "+documentSchema.getName()+" "+ LocalDateTime.now());
    generatedDocument.setDocumentSchemaId(documentSchema.getId());
    generatedDocument.setCreatedDate(LocalDate.now());
    generatedDocumentService.save(generatedDocument);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("filename", "Dokument");
    final ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(document, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return  responseEntity;
}
```